# Select Tab and run code in its fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a tab setup with a VeiwPager and a MainActivity. When one particular tab, "B" is selected I want to Show Fragment B user interface and start doing something. 
The method I have found to do this is to use a LocalBroadcastReceiver in Fragment "B" and have it call a method. The broadcast is sent from Main Activity inside the onTabSelected method.

Is this a good approach?

Comment: As long as you remember to de-register the receiver when the fragment gets destroyed ( and it can, if you are using a state pager adapter for the viewpager), It's all good if it works for you. I personally keep a reference of all the fragments inside the adapter inside a weakreference and use the references to do things when needed, but to everyone their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Activity.class

```
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    setUpviewPager();
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setUpviewPager() {


    ViewPagerAdpater viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdpater(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}


private class ViewPagerAdpater extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    ViewPagerAdpater(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FirsFrag();

            case 1:
                return new FirsFrag();

            case 2:
                return new FirsFrag();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "First Tab";
            case 1:
                return "Second Tab";
            case 2:
                return "Third Tab";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}



Thanks, just run this code, this adapter is FragmentPagerAdpater
```